# Writing a custom function in python, for loop doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to replace values in the data frame column of `dtype` Object.
Replace, `"LF"`,`"low fat"` to `"Low Fat"` and `"reg"` to `"Regular"`

function:

```
  def fat_value_replace(x):
    for x in data:
                  x.replace("LF","Low Fat")
                  x.replace("low fat","Low Fat")
                  x.replace("reg","Regular")
    return x
```

when I apply `df = data.apply(fat_value_replace)` I only get the first value in the for loop, `'Low Fat'` replaced in all observations.

`pd.value_counts(df)` returns:

```
Low Fat    8523
```

Comment: `str.replace` returns values, but does not mutate the value of the string.

Comment: You are changing string of all items, but you return only the last one.. every other items are just lost..

Comment: Sorry, the code got missed up. Actual code :

def fat_value_replace(x):
       for x in data:
                           x.replace("LF","Low Fat")
                           x.replace("low fat","Low Fat")
                           x.replace("reg","Regular")
            return x

Answer (score 0):

**Found the answer. It was really simple.**

```
replacements = {
  'LF': 'Low Fat',
  'low fat':'Low Fat', 
  'reg': 'Regular',
}

df.replace(replacements, inplace=True)
```